# Choosing between 16-bit and 24 bit ADC

Tags: adc, homework

In my application the 16-bit ADC would have enough resolution, but is there any pros choosing 24 bit ADC over a 16 bit ADC, if they otherwise have the same specs?
Both of these would be suitable for my application.

Comment: Better to edit your question, rather than adding comments.

Comment: It 100% depends what your application is.

Comment: @ThePhoton sorry, in this case it's active measuring of ecg and blood pressure

Comment: When you say "both would be suitable", do you mean "16 bits" is sufficient, or that a "16 bit ADC where the low 2-3 bits are noise" is sufficient?  It's much easier to get 16 bits of signal from a 24-bit ADC than from a 16-bit ADC.

Comment: There are important characteristics other than resolution. Do you care about **accuracy**? Linearity? Sampling rate? Power consumption? I doubt very much that they have the same specs in all of these areas.

Comment: what might you learn about the human body, with 24 bits? measuring relaxation of the arteries, as blood-fats stimulate the endothelium to be less relaxed?

Comment: Power-line hum (50/60 Hz) might be a noise source for ECG. A sampling rate at an integer multiple of line frequency can reject this noise. Do both ADC allow sampling rate adjustment?

Answer (score 1):

Noise...assuming you design things right, which will be more challenging with the 24 bit. But you don't need it if 16 bits is good enough. Honestly, I see mostly disadvantages since 16 bit already meets your needs. More cost and design effort to get the most out of the part which you ultimately do not need, Might be a good learning experience though. I do that sometimes to see how far I can push it in something where it doesn't matter if it falls short.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what are you going to do with 24 bit data. If you will be discarding 8 LSB anyway to get 16 bit value then it makes absolutely zero sense to obtain it in the first place. If using all 24 bits will improve functionality of your application enough to justify added cost and software complexity then you can go with that.

Comment: Thanks. This is just an assignment to choose the best ADC for a specific measurement type, so all i have to do is justify why i chose this ADC. So I think i should just choose the 16-bit because I can't really give any reasons why the 24-bit would be any better.